# Positioning of object programmatically in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I want to set a position of an object programmatically. For this I do:

```
youtubeIco.frame.origin.y = 100
```

but nothing. It doesn't change coordinates at all. What is the problem?

And a second question:

when I set in the XCode constraints of webView(for ex: 10(top, left, right, bottom) it disappears. But when I do not set constraints for it, it appears. What is the problem?

I want like this:

[image]

Comment: Rather than manipulating the frame you should manipulate the constraint. You can create an IBOutlet for the constraint to make this easier

Answer (score 5):

You need to set full frame like,

```
youtubeIco.frame = CGRectMake(youtubeIco.frame.origin.x, 100,youtubeIco.frame.size.width,youtubeIco.frame.size.height)
```

Only y-axis change will not do anything  to it, you have to provide full frame for that. or set centre, or offset.

Comment: Try out with removing constraint, if solve then, add constraint except top-align otherwise y position will not change.

Comment: There must be constraint problem, otherwise it works, If possible put more code so we can solve.

Comment: I use it on webView and it works(your code), but on buttons - no. I delete all it constraints, again nothing

Comment: What view did you add youTubeIco to? The positions are relative to the parent view of youTubeIco

Comment: Can you put screen shot of storyboard with button you want to change y position.

Comment: relatively to what? other controlls?

Comment: inside of the view panel, for example? I did add the screenshot what I want

Comment: Is it possible you are editing the wrong size class?

Answer (score 1):

With AutoLayout you can't change a view's frame directly. The constraint puts the object right back where it was.

Instead, you should add constraints that position your views and add IBOutlets to those constraints. Then you use the outlet(s) to change the constant value of the constraint, and the constraint moves your view objects for you. (In this context anything you can display on the screen is a view {a descendant of UIView} including buttons.)

Comment: This way very helpful. Thanks